# Fill array with hash table values ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am new to ruby. I was wondering if there is easy way to do the following:
I have an multi dimensions array = [[10,12],[15,10]]
Which I want to populate with values from an hash table which his keys correspond to the items in the array.

```
hash:
10 - [501, 600]
12 - [700]
15 - [101,103]
```

I actually want all combinations, the output should be:
    `array = [[501,700],[600,700],[101,501],[103,600]]`

I

Comment: Your hash isn't a hash. We need to see the code you've written to solve this, and an explanation for why it doesn't work. Stack Overflow helps fix problems, we're not here to write code for you. Please read "[ask]".

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
dimensions = [[10,12], [15,10]]

mapping = {
  10 => [501, 600],
  12 => [700, 700],
  15 => [101, 103]
}

results = dimensions.map do |dimension_1, dimension_2|
  values_1 = mapping[dimension_1]
  values_2 = mapping[dimension_2]

  values_1.zip values_2
end.flatten(1)


p results
# returns: [[501, 700], [600, 700], [101, 501], [103, 600]]
```

The only thing I've changed is that I've duplicated the 700 value in the input to align the array sizes to simplify it a bit